# Getting all "Anchor Data" variables using solana-py

Tags: python, solana-py

I'm using solana-py to get account info from Token Acccounts on Solana, however the returned data doesn't include the full "Anchor Data" I'm seeing on solana.explorer

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client 
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

# init client 

url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
client = Client(url)

# return parsed info for Token Account

address = Pubkey.from_string("BUvduFTd2sWFagCunBPLupG8fBTJqweLw9DuhruNFSCm")
out = client.get_account_info_json_parsed(address)
```

This call returns tokenAmount, which is something I want, but I also want the "Assets" section from the Anchor Data on the explorer, full url here; https://explorer.solana.com/address/7xS2gz2bTp3fwCC7knJvUWTEU9Tycczu6VhJYKgi1wdz/anchor-account

How do I fetch / call all the data displayed in "Anchor Data" with solana-py or another python library?